# How to CHANGE the account profile picture on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

So, i've installed Xubuntu on my computer and changed the user image (created a 96x96 .jpg and placed it in the Home folder with the name .face). Now I want to use a new image but the .face file disapeared! When I try to place a new file in the folder a get a message saying there's already a file with that name.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Files starting with a dot are hidden files in ubuntu.

You can press CTRL-h to show this files.

Press CTRL-h again to hide them.